# Searching in recursive Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am using Recursion to search an element in my Binary Search Tree but my code stops working if the element is not present in the BST.

```
void tree::searching(node *root,int key)
{
    if(root->key==key||root==NULL)
    {
       cout<<"Congratulation Element found in the BST"<<"\n";
       return;
    } else {
        if(key<root->key)
        {
           searching(root->left,key);
        } else {
           searching(root->right,key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your check for a null-pointer `root` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**

If `root` would be `nullptr` in this statement:

```
    if(root->key==key||root==NULL)
```

you would first dereference a null pointer with `root->key`, which is UB, before checking if it's `NULL`.

**The solution**

Do it the other way round:

```
    if(root==nullptr||root->key==key)
```

In this case, if root is NULL, the the if clause is immediately executed.  Only if root would be not NULL, would the pointer be dereferenced.

***Note:*** you tell that the element was found even if the element is not found (i.e. root reached a nullptr, without ever having encountered the correct key).  Consider having distinct case for nullptr (means that it was not found), and equality (means that it was found).

Answer (score 2):

You're dereferencing a NULL pointer here:

```
if(root->key==key||root==NULL)
{
    cout<<"Congratulation Element found in the BST"<<"\n";
    return;
}
```

The `||` operator evauates the left side first, and if it is value *then* it evaluates the right side.  So you dereference `root` before checking if it is NULL.

Do the NULL check first and return if you find a NULL pointer:

```
void tree::searching(node *root,int key)
{
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    if(root->key==key) {
        cout<<"Congratulation Element found in the BST"<<"\n";
    } else if(key<root->key)
        searching(root->left,key);
    } else {
        searching(root->right,key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, it's worth returning from successful branch as well, as in your case, recursion will just keep happening until `root == nullptr` will happen.

Comment: @JohnCvelth An explicit `return` is superfluous in this case since the program will flow right to the end of the function after the element is found.

Comment: @JohnCvelth On a key match the other else-if and else are not executed, and there is no code after that. In short, it already does return immediately after the match.

Comment: Ticked. Fixes both problems (the null pointer dereference and the broken logic announcing a find on every non-matching terminating leaf node). The only thing I would change is the requirement of both `operator <` and `operator ==` for key comparisons. `if (a < b) ... else if (b < a) ... else matched` One operator. Regardless, nice.

Comment: @WhozCraig, oops, yes. I was inattentive.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing too early. If the programs go to a leaf it will print because the expression in the fist if will be evaluated to true.

```
void tree::searching(node *root,int key)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(root->key==key)
    {
        cout<<"Congratulation Element found in the BST"<<"\n";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(key<root->key)
        {
            searching(root->left,key);
        }
        else
        {
            searching(root->right,key);
        }
    }

 }
```